# cuando guardo un registro actualiza otro de una entidad diferente

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, java-8

estoy trabajando con SpringBoot, JPA y PostgreSQL, todo funciona bien hasta el momento en que guarda registros en una tabla en particular, me actualiza un registro de otra tabla, con la que no tengo ninguna relación directa.

Mis entidades son estas:

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "transaction_logbook_loan_event")
public class Logbook implements Serializable, Comparable<Logbook>{

    private Long id;
    private Long type_id;
    private Long responsible;
    private Long people_id;
    private Long location_id;
    private List<LogbookDetail> detail = new ArrayList<>();
    private ZonedDateTime limitDate = ZonedDateTime.now();
    private ZonedDateTime createdOn = ZonedDateTime.now();

    public Logbook() {
    }

    public Logbook(Long type_id, Long responsible, Long people_id, Long location_id,ZonedDateTime limitDate) {
        this.type_id = type_id;
        this.responsible = responsible;
        this.people_id = people_id;
        this.location_id = location_id;
        this.limitDate = limitDate;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "LogbookGenerator")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "LogbookGenerator",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
            parameters = {@org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "transaction_logbook_loan_event_id_seq")}
    )
    @Column(name = "tlgle_id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "tlgle_type_id")
    public Long getType_id() {
        return type_id;
    }

    public void setType_id(Long type_id) {
        this.type_id = type_id;
    }

    @Column(name = "tlgle_responsible_id")
    public Long getResponsible() {
        return responsible;
    }

    public void setResponsible(Long responsible) {
        this.responsible = responsible;
    }

    @Column(name = "tlgle_people_id")
    public Long getPeople_id() {
        return people_id;
    }

    public void setPeople_id(Long people_id) {
        this.people_id = people_id;
    }

    @Column(name = "tlgle_location_id")
    public Long getLocation_id() {
        return location_id;
    }

    public void setLocation_id(Long location_id) {
        this.location_id = location_id;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tlgle_id")
    public List<LogbookDetail> getDetail() {
        return detail;
    }

    public void setDetail(List<LogbookDetail> detail) {
        this.detail = detail;
    }

    @Column(name = "tlgle_return_date")
    public ZonedDateTime getLimitDate() {
        return limitDate;
    }

    public void setLimitDate(ZonedDateTime returnDate) {
        this.limitDate = returnDate;
    }

    @Column(name = "tlgle_created_on")
    public ZonedDateTime getCreatedOn() {
        return createdOn;
    }

    public void setCreatedOn(ZonedDateTime createdOn) {
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Logbook o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

y

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

@Entity
@Table(name = "transaction_logbook_detail")
public class LogbookDetail implements Serializable, Comparable<LogbookDetail>{

    private Long id;
    private Long tlgle_id;
    private String tag_id;
    private boolean executed;
    private String description;
    private ZonedDateTime createdOn = ZonedDateTime.now();

    public LogbookDetail() {
    }

    public LogbookDetail(Long tlgle_id, String tag_id, boolean executed, String descripction) {
        this.tlgle_id = tlgle_id;
        this.tag_id = tag_id;
        this.executed = executed;
        this.description = descripction;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "LogbookDetailGenerator")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "LogbookDetailGenerator",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
            parameters = {@org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "transaction_logbook_detail_id_seq")}
    )
    @Column(name = "tlgbk_detail_id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "tlgle_id")
    public Long getTlgle_id() {
        return tlgle_id;
    }

    public void setTlgle_id(Long tlgle_id) {
        this.tlgle_id = tlgle_id;
    }

    @Column(name = "tlgbk_detail_tag_id")
    public String getTag_id() {
        return tag_id;
    }

    public void setTag_id(String tag_id) {
        this.tag_id = tag_id;
    }

    @Column(name = "tlgbk_detail_executed")
    public boolean isExecuted() {
        return executed;
    }

    public void setExecuted(boolean executed) {
        this.executed = executed;
    }

    @Column(name = "tlgbk_detail_description")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Column(name = "tlgbk_detail_created_on")
    public ZonedDateTime getCreatedOn() {
        return createdOn;
    }

    public void setCreatedOn(ZonedDateTime createdOn) {
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(LogbookDetail o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

cuando guarda el registro hace esto:

```
2019-01-28 10:08:33.800 DEBUG 10368 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select nextval ('transaction_logbook_loan_event_id_seq')
2019-01-28 10:08:33.833 DEBUG 10368 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into transaction_logbook_loan_event (tlgle_created_on, tlgle_return_date, tlgle_location_id, tlgle_people_id, tlgle_responsible_id, tlgle_type_id, tlgle_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2019-01-28 10:08:33.841 DEBUG 10368 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : update tag set tag_company_code=?, tag_create_event=?, tag_created_on=?, location_id=?, tag_lock=?, packing_unit_id=?, tag_pointer=?, tag_serial=?, state_id=?, tag_type_id=?, tag_update_event=?, tag_updated_on=? where tag_id=?
2019-01-28 10:08:33.847 DEBUG 10368 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select nextval ('transaction_logbook_detail_id_seq')
2019-01-28 10:08:33.853 DEBUG 10368 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into transaction_logbook_detail (tlgbk_detail_created_on, tlgbk_detail_description, tlgbk_detail_executed, tlgbk_detail_tag_id, tlgle_id, tlgbk_detail_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2019-01-28 10:08:33.857 DEBUG 10368 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select nextval ('transaction_logbook_detail_id_seq')
2019-01-28 10:08:33.863 DEBUG 10368 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into transaction_logbook_detail (tlgbk_detail_created_on, tlgbk_detail_description, tlgbk_detail_executed, tlgbk_detail_tag_id, tlgle_id, tlgbk_detail_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2019-01-28 10:08:33.875 DEBUG 10368 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select tag0_.tag_id as tag_id1_47_, tag0_.tag_company_code as tag_comp2_47_, tag0_.tag_create_event as tag_crea3_47_, tag0_.tag_created_on as tag_crea4_47_, tag0_.location_id as location5_47_, tag0_.tag_lock as tag_lock6_47_, tag0_.packing_unit_id as packing_7_47_, tag0_.tag_pointer as tag_poin8_47_, tag0_.tag_serial as tag_seri9_47_, tag0_.state_id as state_i10_47_, tag0_.tag_type_id as tag_typ11_47_, tag0_.tag_update_event as tag_upd12_47_, tag0_.tag_updated_on as tag_upd13_47_ from tag tag0_ where tag0_.tag_serial=?
2019-01-28 10:08:57.687 DEBUG 10368 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select count(logbook0_.tlgle_id) as col_0_0_ from transaction_logbook_loan_event logbook0_
```

Y esta es la estructura de as tablas

```
    CREATE SEQUENCE transaction_logbook_loan_event_id_seq
        START WITH 1
        INCREMENT BY 1
        NO MINVALUE
        NO MAXVALUE
        CACHE 1;

    CREATE TABLE transaction_logbook_loan_event (
        tlgle_id bigint DEFAULT nextval('transaction_logbook_loan_event_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
        tlgle_type_id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0::bigint,
        tlgle_responsible_id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0::bigint,
        tlgle_people_id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0::bigint,
        tlgle_location_id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0::bigint,
        tlgle_return_date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL default now()::timestamp with time zone,
        tlgle_created_on timestamp with time zone NOT NULL default now()::timestamp with time zone
    );


    CREATE SEQUENCE transaction_logbook_detail_id_seq
        START WITH 1
        INCREMENT BY 1
        NO MINVALUE
        NO MAXVALUE
        CACHE 1;

    CREATE TABLE transaction_logbook_detail (
        tlgbk_detail_id b

igint DEFAULT nextval('transaction_logbook_detail_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
    tlgle_id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0::bigint,
    tlgbk_detail_tag_id text NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::text,
    tlgbk_detail_executed boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false::boolean,
    tlgbk_detail_description text NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::text,
    tlgbk_detail_created_on timestamp with time zone NOT NULL default now()::timestamp with time zone );

ALTER TABLE ONLY transaction_logbook_loan_event
    ADD CONSTRAINT transaction_logbook_loan_event_ck UNIQUE (tlgle_id,tlgle_type_id);

ALTER TABLE ONLY transaction_logbook_loan_event
    ADD CONSTRAINT transaction_logbook_loan_event_pkey PRIMARY KEY (tlgle_id);

ALTER TABLE transaction_logbook_detail ADD FOREIGN KEY(tlgle_id) REFERENCES transaction_logbook_loan_event(tlgle_id);

ALTER TABLE transaction_logbook_loan_event ADD FOREIGN KEY(tlgle_type_id) REFERENCES transaction_type(transaction_type_id);

ALTER TABLE ONLY transaction_logbook_detail
    ADD CONSTRAINT transaction_logbook_detail_pkey PRIMARY KEY (tlgbk_detail_id);
```

Comment: `guarda registros en una tabla en particular, me actualiza un registro de otra tabla` = ¿cuáles son esas tablas que menciona?, por favor redacte su pregunta para que todos los que la lean entiendan a qué se está refiriendo. Además de copiar código, es necesario una explicación clara. Lea: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que no están relacionadas cuando un `Logbook` tiene una lista de `LogbookDetail`?